# Dynamic sum formula without column names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm generating Excel xml file from external system. Now I'm facing issue with summary cells. Of course I could just sum data already in the other system but I really would like to get real sum formulas to the file.

Is there any way to sum cells without knowing column name? Is there e.g. something like this (would sum current column data from 1th row to 10th row):

`=SUM(THISCOLUMN1:THISCOLUMN10)`

Would that be good approach or what do you think? In my case the column count can vary every time an Excel file is generated.

If not possible then I think I have to convert current column number index to Excel column name syntax in my program.

Simplified example: http://pastebin.com/YMxggt7v

Comment: A possible answer depends on how you are "generating Excel xml file from external system". If you are able using `R1C1` formulas it would be `=SUM(R1C:R10C)`.

Comment: I assume that needs changes to Excel settings? I'm afraid that won't be possible. It should work with default Excel setup.

Comment: No, no changes to Excel settings needed. As I said it depends on how you are "generating Excel xml file from external system". So how? Please show at least the XML you would generating with a normal `SUM` formula.

Comment: My example seems only be working in LibreOffice Calc. However the final solution should work in MS Excel also.

Comment: Not nice to get minus votes. Just wondering why, how can I improve my future posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proper solution with help of Axel Richter:

```
Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R[-2]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])">
  <Data ss:Type="Number"></Data>
</Cell>
```

Then I just need to change R[-2] according to line count I'm having.

Comment: How does one modify this so the end row is dynamic based upon the data received?
=SUM(R[4]C[10]:R[3420]C[10])  This shows for a report with 3427 rows. However, some may have 1,000, 5,000, or 300.

This shows a total of

Answer (score 0):

The following XML works for me with Excel 2007:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Tabelle1">
  <Table>
   <Row ss:Index="11">
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R1C:R10C)"></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R1C:R10C)"></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R1C:R10C)"></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=SUM(R1C:R10C)"></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Saved this as *.xml and opened it with Excel using File-Open. Or saved this as *.xls and opened it with double click.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx for a reference to XML Spreadsheet 2003.

Comment: Ok, that is even more elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Someone downvoted this post also. I think it was helpful and clear.

Comment: Since everyone can vote anonymous, some votes will not be clear at all. Maybe the voter has not even understand what the question is about. But don't worry, in the whole SO is very helpful nevertheless.